# $I=\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}=\left(-\infty, 0\right)\cup\left(0, +\infty\right)$? And why $-\dfrac{1}{x}$ is not increasing in $I$?

Tags: real-analysis

I have two questions:

> $1$- Is this correct or wrong and why please.
> $$\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}=\left(-\infty, 0\right)\cup\left(0, +\infty\right)?$$

Now if it is correct. It is the turn of my $2$nd question.

> $2$- Let say that I have a function $f: \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that is increasing in $\left(-\infty, 0\right)$ and increasing in $\left(0, +\infty\right)$.
>
> Can I say that $f$ is increasing in $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$?

I really would like to see a proof but not a no or yes. Thank you in advance.

P.S.

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $x\neq0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $x\in\left(-\infty, 0\right)\cup\left(0, \infty\right).$

For the second question I say yes it is correct but I do not have a proof. Using the graph of $f$, $f$ is increasing in $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$.

Comment: Yes! That is correct.

Comment: Are you aware that $\mathbb R = (-\infty, +\infty)$?

Comment: It is in fact correct. Notation $ (a,b) $ is used to mean the open interval in $ \mathbb R $ from $ a $ to $ b > a $. $ \mathbb R $ is the open interval $ (-\infty,+\infty) $, so removing a single point $ x $ (a closed set, in the standard topology of $ \mathbb R $) will result in two disjoint open sets $ (-\infty,x) $ and $ (x,+\infty) $.

Comment: equality of two sets $A,B$ is shown by showing that $A\subset B$ and $B\subset A$ are both true.

Comment: If your confusion is about $\pm \infty$, sometimes $\mathbb{R}^*$ is used to indicate $[-\infty,+\infty]$.

Comment: For the second question, no.

Comment: I don't know what's going on here, maybe the OP edited the question. But the answer for the current question is a blatant **NO**, it is not correct.

Comment: @GitGud why $\textbf{NOT}$?

Comment: @zighalo Consider $f(x)=\begin{cases} x, &\text{if }x<0\\ x-1000, &\text{if }x>0\end{cases}.$ Near left of $0$, it close to $0$, to the right of $0$ it is close to $-1000$, it decreases.

Comment: @GitGud Thanks. But $0\notin\mathrm{dom} f$ so the function is discontinuous am I right?

Comment: @zighalo If it were to be defined at $0$, it would be discontinuous.But it isn't defined at $0$. I didn't include $0$ in the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a formal proof:

Try $x \in \Bbb R \setminus \{0\} $ which would mean that $x \in \Bbb R$ but $x \neq 0$. Hence $x \lt 0$  or $x \gt 0$ depending on which $x \in (- \infty , 0)$ or $x \in (0, \infty)$, either way $\Bbb R \setminus \{0\} \subseteq \left(-\infty, 0\right)\cup\left(0, +\infty\right)$.

$x \in \left(-\infty, 0\right)\cup\left(0, +\infty\right)$ means $x \in \Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$ quite obviously and hence the set equality follows.